# Trouble when using Greek characters in \part and \chapter: Capitalization does not work

Tags: hyperref, babel, greek

I am setting up a document for PhD thesis in Greek and I have troubles when I am typing Greek characters in `\section{}`, `\part{}`, `\chapter{}`. When it compiles the section turns out fine although I get many hyperref warnings, however, when it comes to parts and chapters it compiles unrecognized characters.

For the Minimal Working Example (MWE) the warnings I get are like this:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
>   (hyperref)                removing `\begingroup' on input line 17.

The error I get is:

> ! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 909 = U+038D,
>
> (ucs)                possibly declared in uni-3.def.
>
> (ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.
>
> See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.17 \part{Τίτλος μέρους}
>
> ? h
>
> Character's name unknown
>
> Character is not defined in uni-*.def files.
>
> Enter I! to define the glyph.

---

> PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 4)
>
> Errors: 1   Warnings: 97   Bad Boxes: 0

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek.polutoniko]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Τίτλος μέρους}

\chapter{Τίτλος κεφαλαίου}

\section{Τίτλος}

\chapter{\en Chapter name}

\end{document}
```

This is part of the output:

[image: Part 1 and name of part1]

[image: chapter name and section name]

Comment: Use `utf8` instead of `utf8x` and remove `\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}`. Where is the `thesis` class available?

Comment: I have done what you said, still the same. I am not sure what you mean by "where is the thesis class available?". It is under texmf/tex/latex/thesis.

Comment: Oh, the one that comes with MiKTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thesis` class you're using has been unsupported since 1996.

The main problem is that it uses `\uppercase` instead of `\MakeUppercase` in several places. Another problem is using `utf8x` which is unmaintained and buggy.

A minor problem is `hyperref` not understanding `\acctonos` and `\textfinalsigma`, which can be solved by adding support for it.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}

\usepackage[english,greek.polutoniko]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%% fix the faulty bits of thesis.cls
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\uppercase\expandafter}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\uppercase\expandafter}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  unicode,
  colorlinks=true,
  pdfstartview=FitV,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=black,
]{hyperref}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\textalpha}{\9003\254}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\textepsilon}{\9003\255}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\texteta}{\9003\256}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\textiota}{\9003\257}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\textomicron}{\9003\314}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\acctonos}{PU}{\textomega}{\9003\316}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textfinalsigma}{PU}{\9003\302}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Τίτλος μέρους}

\chapter{Τίτλος κεφαλαίου}

\section{Τίτλος}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\chapter{Chapter name}

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

If a chapter is in English it's better to use `otherlanguage` around it.